# How to checkout configurable product in REST API in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

- After adding configurable product in cart
- How to checkout configurable product in REST API in magento 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Get Customer Token**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?
username=aditya.shah@test.com&password=test@123
```

- `method : POST`

---

**2. Get Cart ID (Quote ID) - using customer id.**

> This will return quote id, which will be used for placing an order.

```
http://magento-host/rest/V1/carts/mine
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`

---

**3. Add Configurable product in cart.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items
```

.

---

**4. Get & put Shipping Information.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information
```

---

**5. Get payment method.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/75/payment-methods
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`

---

**6. Place an order.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/order
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`
- `body data : json`

---

```
{
    "paymentMethod": {
        "method": "checkmo"
    }
}
```

**And finally, this will return order ID, which you just placed!**